# Как получить данные из xml файла при загрузке страницы?

Tags: javascript, xml

Нужно получить данные из файла xml, и подставить данные из него в html.
Мне нужно достать из него текст 50$ и More Information. Как это сделать используя javascript?
Это код файла:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <data>
        <Texts>
            <Price><![CDATA[50 $]]></Price>
            <CTA_text><![CDATA[MORE INFORMATION]]></CTA_text>
        </Texts>
    </data>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

С помощью jQuery запросто:

```js
var xml = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> <data>        <Texts>            <Price><![CDATA[50 $]]></Price>   <CTA_text><![CDATA[MORE INFORMATION]]></CTA_text> </Texts> </data>';
var xmlDoc = $.parseXML( xml );
var price = $( xmlDoc ).find( "Price" );
alert(price.text());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseXML/